# Linux Default App Developed in Java

Tags: application-development, java, development

Different Linux and Ubuntu releases have different software included by default -- for example, transmission, Firefox, and Banshee have all been default applications.

As far as I know, most of these applications have been developed using C, or C++ (vala also), or another language that will be compiled into native Linux binary files.

Is there any software which has been developed in Java and has become one of Ubuntu's default apps? (Excluding some IDEs such as NetBeans and Eclipse.)

Comment: Probably not a good fit for AskUbuntu, since it's not specifically an Ubuntu question.  The Ubuntu for phones projects will not doubt turn a few things on their heads so things could change radically in the future.  At the moment though the question is probably off topic for us.

Comment: @ehsun7b This *might* be considered on-topic on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com). I'll try to answer this for Ubuntu specifically, but if you're asking about distributions in general, this isn't the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LibreOffice](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LibreOffice) is the most obvious example of a default program in Ubuntu that is written in Java and is not a software development tool.

LibreOffice is Ubuntu's default office suite. (It is a fork of [OpenOffice.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenOffice), which [was previously](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/open-source/ubuntu-opts-for-libreoffice-over-oracles-openoffice/8122) Ubuntu's default office suite and is also written in Java.)